# Drawing line to HTML5 canvas not working using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am using the following codes to draw a line to html canvas. But unfortunately i am not seeing any line in the canvas. I am not finding any error even.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

</head>
<body>
    <br> <br> <br>
        <input id="start" type="button" value="Start" onclick="startstop()" />
        <input type="button" value="Turn Left" />
        <input type="button" value="Turn Right" />
         <br> <br>

        <canvas id="Canvas" style="width:800px; height: 600px; border: 1px solid black;"> </canvas>

         <script>

             function startstop(){
                 var elem = document.getElementById("start");
                if (elem.value==="Start")
                {
                    elem.value = "Stop";
                    var mycanvas=document.getElementById("Canvas");
                   // alert(mycanvas);
                    var ctx=mycanvas.getContext('2d');
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.moveTo(10,400);
                    ctx.lineTo(200,400); 
                    ctx.lineWidth=10;
                    ctx.strokeStyle="#ff0000";
                    ctx.stroke();     
                }
                   else
                       elem.value = "Start";
             }
         </script>
</body>
```

Here is the jsfiddle of the code http://jsfiddle.net/8ebLLwa9/
Can anyone help me too find the mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your canvas height/width should be properties on the canvas itself, not a style attribute:

```
<canvas id='Canvas' width="800px" height="600px" style="border: 1px solid black;"></canvas>
```

Also, for your jsfiddle, change the loading state from "onLoad" to "No wrap - in head"

Comment: Thanks that helps. But i astonish why the height and width attributes inside style shouldn't work. As they appear same when i was trying to inspect element using browser

Answer (score 2):

Define your canvas using the attributes width and height insetad of the css styles:

```
<canvas id='Canvas' width='800' height='600' style="border: 1px solid black;"> </canvas>
```